# Start Menu running slow. What is the reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pygame

The playable game runs perfectly fine, with absolutely no lag. However, my Start Menu is incredibly slow. What is the reason?? Here is the relevant code:

```
def message_display(text, fontsize, color, itemx, itemy):
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', fontsize)
    render = font.render(text, True, color)
    render_rect = render.get_rect()
    render_rect.center = (itemx/2),(itemy/2)
    gameDisplay.blit(render, render_rect)

    time.sleep(2)


def button(bw, bh, bx, by, msg, col1, col2,fontsi):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if bx < mouse[0] < bx + bw and by < mouse[1] < by + bh:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, col1, (bx, by, bw, bh))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, col2, (bx, by, bw, bh))

    message_display(msg, fontsi, black, bx*2+bw, by*2+bh)   


def game_intro():
    intro = True

    b1w = 100
    b1h = 75
    b1x = 150
    b1y = 450

    b2w = 100
    b2h = 75
    b2x = 550
    b2y = 450

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_display("Driving Mayhem", 90, black, display_width, display_height)

        button(b1w, b1h, b1x, b1y, "Go!", dark_green, bright_green, 30)
        button(b2w, b2h, b2x, b2y, "Quit", dark_red, bright_red, 30)



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

My guess is because, in the Buttons() function, every time a new mouse location is met, it is drawing a new rectangle. If this is the case, how would I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you call `time.sleep(2)` in `message_display`, which will stop your game for 2 seconds.

So every tick of this loop takes at least 6 seconds, because `message_display` is called 3 times.

Just remove the line.